# algorithm: how to compare two groupings

Tags: algorithm, mapreduce

I have two sets of groupings of some numbers (or strings). Each group will have some ID (number) and the same groups might have different IDs in two groupings. I would like to perform some kind of diffs on these two groupings and am wondering if there are such algorithms to use :) If there is a map reduce implementation available, it will be even better.

Here are some examples to clarify since I am not sure my terminology is easy to understand. Let's say there are 5 numbers of 1,2,3,4 and 5.

In Grouping (1), there are two groups:

  Group 1 has 1 and 2.
  Group 2 has 3, 4 and 5.

In Grouping (2), there are three groups:

  Group 1 has 3 and 4.
  Group 2 has 1 and 2.
  Group 3 has 5.

Then diff tool should recognize Group 1 from Grouping (1) and Group 2 from Grouping (2) are the same and the element 5 of Group 2 from Grouping (1) has broken out as a new group in Grouping (2) or something like that.

Comment: Are the groups sets? (order is not important, no dupes per group)?

Comment: I should have been more specific. Let me edit my question.

Comment: If ordering does matter, one could perform HASHs of each group within a grouping as a way of creating group IDs, and simply compare group IDs between groupings.  If ordering doesnt matter than you would have to perform pre-ordering within your groups, but afterwards the same hashing could work.